# Como preguntarle al usuario una confirmacion de eliminar objeto?

Tags: php, html, eloquent

tengo un inconveniente que cuando el usuario quiere eliminar un post se elimina sin mas, pero yo quiero preguntarle al usuario alguna confirmacion de si desea eliminarlo, estoy trabajando con php, eloquent, twige illuminate, por ahora tengo esta parte en el controlador del get el cual paso un parametro que es el (id) del post que se va a eliminar.

> En esta primera parte tengo el index de administracion, de aqui mando el get para la eliminacion de post al controlador

```
{% extends "layout.twig" %}
{% block content %}

    <a class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom: 10px" href="{{ 'admin/posts' | url }}">Back</a>
    <form action="{{ 'admin/posts/update' | url }}" method="post">
        {% if errors %}
            {% include ('partials/errors.twig') %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if result %}

            <div class="alert alert-success">
                Success!!!
            </div>

        {% endif %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <h2>{{ blogPost.title }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputImg">Image</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="img" id="inputImg" value="{{ blogPost.img_url }}">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ blogPost.id }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputContent">Content</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="inputContent" rows="10">{{ blogPost.content }}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px" type="submit" value="Save">
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

> Aqui tengo el controlador el cual recibe el parametro del id que se va a eliminar

```
 public function getDelete($id){

        BlogPost::destroy($id);
        header('Location:' . BASE_URL . 'admin/posts');
    }
```

> a lo que le quiero implementar la confirmacion es a una ancla, delete:

```
<tbody>
                {% for blogPost in blogPosts %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ blogPost.title }}</td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ "admin/posts/update/" | url }}{{ blogPost.id }}">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ 'admin/posts/delete/' | url }}{{ blogPost.id }}">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo puedes hacer con js o con jquery haciendo uso de confirm y de los id de los inputs.

agregas un id a tu botón

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit">
```

el script con jQuery seria

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit").click(function(){
    if(confirm("seguro de eliminar este post")){
     var id = $("#id").val();
     location.href= 'turuta/'+id+'/';
 }else{
            console.log('cancela la eliminada');
        }
 });

</script>
```

me dices como te va

Comment: se me habia olvidado colocar la otra parte, es que realmente necesito eso, pero no con un input si no con un ancla, estaba probando con SweetAlert2 que me parecio bastante bueno, peor no se como implementarlo con un ancla

Comment: es lo mismo, solo debes agregarle el id a la etiqueta <a>

Comment: vale amigo, ya lo pude hacer muchisimas gracias

Comment: a okey, con gusto espero te funcione bien

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar el codigo que te paso @camilo y luego de la confirmacion haces el llamado a la funcion getDelete($id), algo asi

```
<script type='text/javascript' 
 src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#submit").click(function(){
    if(confirm("seguro de eliminar este post")){
        getDelete('#id');
    }else{
        console.log('cancela la eliminada');
    }
});
</script>
```